# Check if Date field is empty

Tags: date, conditional

How can I check if a Date field is empty or blank?
I tried this statement:

```
if(project.Current_Launch_Date__c==null)
```

But I don't get the desired result, even if I delete the date value, it still does not go inside the if statement.

This is the Debug Log:

USER_DEBUG|[138]|DEBUG|*** Current_Launch_Date__c: 2017-04-03 00:00:00

Comment: What is the data type of `Current_Launch_Date__c`? because every variable in apex is assigned `null` by default. So ideally `if(project.Current_Launch_Date__c==null)` this should work.

Comment: the data type is Date

Comment: Then `if(project.Current_Launch_Date__c==null)` is correct. Try adding `System.debug(project.Current_Launch_Date__c)` before `if` and check the value of `project.Current_Launch_Date__c`. It must be having some value in it.

Comment: can you share your complete code or any debug logs related to this ?

Comment: This is what I get when I run a debug log:
USER_DEBUG|[138]|DEBUG|*** Current_Launch_Date__c: 2017-04-03 00:00:00

This is a default value, it wasn't chosen by the user.

Comment: Check if a workflow or a process is setting the date - it's clearly setting the date to today's date.

Comment: Is there any other method to check if the field is empty instead of '==null' that I can use?

Comment: if custom field `Current_Launch_Date__c` is defined with a default formula value = `TODAY()`, then a new object will never have a null value unless cleared in the UI before the SAVE